# Play Framework's PathBindable on abstract parent class

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I'm using Play 2.2.x with Java and trying to use inheritance with PathBindable.

Say I have an abstract parent class "Vehicle", with child classes "Car" and "Truck" (seen below).  I'd like implement PathBindable on just the parent Vehicle class.  However I cannot seem to get that to work where I can pass a variable of type Car as a URL parameter.  When trying to compile, I get the error:

```
[error] GET  /open-trunk/:car   controllers.CarThings.openTrunk(car: Car)
[error] /xxx/routes:xxx: No URL path binder found for type Car. Try to implement an implicit PathBindable for this type.
```

Passing a generic Vehicle variable compiles fine.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this without having to pass a Car as a Vehicle and casting in the controller methods?

---

Vehicle.java

```
import play.mvc.PathBindable;
public abstract class Vehicle implements PathBindable<Vehicle> {
    .... // Overrides for bind, unbind & javascriptUnbind
}
```

Car.java

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    ....
    public void openUpTrunk() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Truck.java

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle {
    ....
}
```

routes

```
....
GET  /open-trunk/:car   controllers.CarThings.openTrunk(car: Car)
....
```

CarThings.java

```
public class CarThings extends Controller {
    public static openTrunk(Car car) {
        car.openUpTrunk();
        ....
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking that this is not possible, as the "bind" function when implementing PathBindable requires a new instance of the class to be instantiated, and I'm assuming that the Play source is trying to instantiate the abstract parent class, which it obviously cannot do.

Comment: Trying to get around this, I implemented PathBindable on the child classes.  When doing that, I need duplicate each route and make unique controller functions for each type.  This is a PITA; when calling the routes in the view or controller, I need to first determine which type of class I'm working with, and call the corresponding route.  So, instead of that ugly solution, I've pretty much ditched PathBindable as it doesn't seem to work in my scenario and instead am passing the Integer ID's of the objects and then turning them back into the correct object myself, rather than using the bind.